# Nystrom method matrix approximation error dependency on the spectrum of the matrix to be approximated

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, approximation, matrix-rank

Why does the error of Nystrom approximation for matrices depend on the spectrum of the matrix to be approximated and why does it decrease with the rank of the matrix?

Comment: The percent error is given as $\text{Percent Error } =  \frac{\| G - \tilde{G}_k \|_F }{\| G \|_F } \times 100 $ where $ \| \cdot \|_F$ is the Frobenius norm which is equal to the spectral radius (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621659/when-is-the-frobenius-norm-equal-to-the-spectral-radius). See section 4.1 and 4.3 here https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1408/1408.2044.pdf

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks for your comment so the reference to my question is http://proceedings.mlr.press/v70/oglic17a/oglic17a.pdf however I am not able to digest it very well from the paper I am linking.

Comment: I think the important part for the error bounds is in section 2 it says, "Then, at the low rank approximation $ \tilde{H}_{X \mid Z}^* = V_K \Lambda_K V_K^T  $ the Schatten p-norm attains its minimum. There's a link for Golub's book or you can read this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation).  There's another bit that may be useful below that paragraph 2 beneath corollary 6 states that $ \| H - H_K \|_2 $ depends on the spectrum and decreases with K. You can see that's equal to $\sigma_{K+1}$. Singular values are ordered and decrease monotonically to the point it becomes 0

Comment: It depends on the spectrum 1) because of the norm 2) because of how the norm works for positive semidefinite matrices. It should decrease with an increase in K because that error will give you a smaller singular value as K increases and you're making up more of the space.